# Reconnect to a peripheral without restarting scan in noble

Tags: node.js

I am writing a basic program using 'noble'. It goes like this, whenever a peripheral connects to noble instance, I store the id of peripheral. 
Now, suppose peripheral somehow disconnects, then how can I reconnect using the id of peripheral which I stored earlier.

Note : I don't want to restart scan.